# A fast modern network filesystem to replace VirtualBox's shared folder emulation

Tags: virtualbox, performance, filesystems, network-shares, shared-folders

My work code repository is stored in host Linux system, and is accessed from Windows guest; currently, guest can access the repo via 'shared folder' which looks like a samba emulation.

But, it just feels slow in terms of retrieving file lists / file change notifications; Visual Studio starts for minutes (same project loads in seconds from VM's storage), SmartGIT can't detect which files were updated and so on;
Currently, moving the repo onto a new virtualbox drive doesn't looks like a viable solution for me; not because of disk space or encryption issues (actually it's easier to have a large encrypted container on the second hd..), but due to the fact some projects are used from host environment too, and a number of smaller infrastructure issues, so.. finding a better network FS seems like a best hack to me

- A: Does native samba offers better performance than virtualbox's emulated samba in the "billion of small files" scenario?
- B: What are other possible alternatives for Windows client? webdav folders, fast ftp emulated folders, etc?

Comment: Why are you accessing a "shared folder" instead of connecting to the repo (server) in the normal manner? I haven't used smartGit, but typically, you would make a local folder and then mark it in some way, pointing it to the server. I know that for SVN, you are not supposed to use the native file system to copy, paste, move etc. files in a local checkout (you use the svn commands). By using samba to tunnel through from the guest OS, aren't you doing and end-run around the host GIT hooks?

Comment: @horatio shortest possible not-really-an-excuse: >20gb multi-os multi-branch project full-synched to laptop to enable offline working from different locations.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a samba share in the Linux host and have the Windows guest map to that.

We can use the VirtualBox Internal Network for speed.

Let's say the Linux host has an 'VBox Internal Network' IP of 10.0.0.2. Then set up a samba instance on the Linux host and make sure it can listen on 10.0.0.2.

Then just map \10.0.0.2\yourshare to Z:\ or whatever on your Windows guest.

Comment: While this does answer the question, it's quite low in quality. Can you maybe define the steps the user would take? We want to be a worthwhile resource on the Internet, and this answer won't cut it as is. Feel free to [edit] it to make it a better answer

Comment: Edited the answer.